# Proof Involving Greatest Lower Bounds

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$glb(S + T) = glb(S) + glb(T)$ where $S + T = \{s + t|s \in S,t \in T\}$

My question is, how would I prove this statement?

EDIT: 
yes, glb means greatest lower bound basically. And I called glb(S) and glb(T) $a$ and $b$ respectively, and said that $(a+b)\leq glb(S+T)$, and if $c\leq glb(S+T)$, then $(a+b) \geq c$, for all elements in $S+T$. I had no trouble proving the first part, but I'm stuck on the second.
And yes, S and T are both sets of real numbers.

Comment: By glb you mean infimum? And what did you try?

Comment: yes, glb means greatest lower bound basically. And I called glb(S) and glb(S) "a" and "b" respectively, and said that (a+b)<=glb(S+T), and if c<=glb(S+T), then (a+b)>=c, for all elements in S+T. I had no trouble proving the first part, but I'm stuck on the second.

Comment: Please also read about how to write maths using MathJax/LaTeX. Thanks.

Comment: Are S and T subsets of the real numbers.  I know I'm being picky, but this need not be true for other spaces without the archemedian property or the least upper bound property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you already know, that for $S,T \subset \mathbb R$, $a=\inf(S)$, $b=\inf(T)$ the following equation hold
$$ a+b \leq \inf(S+T).$$
To do the second part try contradiction. Assume, that $c=\inf(S+T) > a+b,$ can you construct $x \in S+T$ such that $a+b<x<c,$ that would be contradiction with with $c$ being lower bound and therefore $c=a+b$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it by proving the contrapositive of the second statement using epsilon and delta.

Comment: Yes playing with $\epsilon$ is the right way. If you are done, you can accept the answer to "close" the question.